# finding maximum of avreage?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
select title,avgstrs
from( select avg(R1.stars) as avgstrs,Movie.title
      from Movie,Rating R1 
      where R1.mID=Movie.mID
      group by R1.mID) as Avrg
where(select max(avgstrs));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select avg(R1.stars) as avgstrs, m.title
from Movie m join
     Rating R1 
     on R1.mID = m.mID
group by R1.mID
order by avgstrs desc
limit 1;
```

If this helps, promise that you will learn proper, explicit `join` syntax and never use commas in the `from` clause again.